# Solving differential equation with initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation with initial conditions:

```
ode = (λ x y[x])/Sqrt[1 - x] + y''[x] == 0
ic = {y[1] == 0, y'[1] == 1}
DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
```

But do not know how to actually solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think *Mathematica* can find a solution to this problem.  Are you sure you've stated it correctly?  Please use accepted *Mathematica* syntax... terms using useless parentheses and asterisks (for multiplication) are quite awkward.  Also, use `y''[x]` to be consistent with your other derivatives.  Moreover, your list of arguments for `DSolve` should not have a *sublist* of initial conditions... just entries.  (See the documentation.)

Comment: @ David-G.-Stork there is nothing wrong with `(x) ` here, just additional parentheses, but correct syntax. You are right with the sublist. I think that's the problem here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

The easiest and fast way only numerically.

```
sol = First@
With[{λ = 1}, 
NDSolve[{z''[x] + (λ*x)/Sqrt[1 - x]*z[x] == 0, 
z[999/1000] == 0, z'[999/1000] == 1}, z, {x, -2, 2}]];
```

**METHOD 2**

Use by Series.

```
n = 6;
y = Sum[c[i]*x^i, {i, 0, n}] + O[x]^(n + 1);
ODE = D[y, {x, 2}] + (λ*x)/Sqrt[1 - x]*y == 0;
Y = Normal[y /. Solve[LogicalExpand[ODE], Table[c[i], {i, 1, n}]]] // 
Quiet;
Sol2 = Simplify@
First[Y /. 
Solve[{Y == 0 /. x -> 1, D[Y, x] == 1 /. x -> 1}, {c[0], c[1]}]];
Plot[{z[x] /. sol, Sol2 /. λ -> 1}, {x, -2, 2}, 
PlotLegends -> {"NDSolve", "Series"}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thin, {Thick, Dashed}}] // Quiet
```

[image]

**Other way**.

```
sol=First@With[{λ = 1}, 
NDSolve[{z''[x] + (λ*x)/Sqrt[1 - x]*z[x] == 0, 
z[999/1000] == 0, z'[999/1000] == 1}, z, {x, -2, 2}]]; data = 
Table[{x, z[x] /. sol}, {x, -2, 2, 0.01}];
k = 5; Sol = Fit[data, Table[x^n, {n, 0, k}], x]

Plot[{z[x] /. sol, Re@Sol}, {x, -2, 2}, 
PlotLegends -> {"NDSolve", "FitData"}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thin, {Thick, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

**METHOD 3**

Analytically.
$$y''(x)+A(x) y(x)=0  \tag{1}$$,were A(x) is:$$A(x)=\frac{\lambda  x}{\sqrt{1-x}} \tag{2}$$
In order to find general solution of Eq.(1) let us introduce new variable:
$$y'=y*z \tag{3}$$
derivative of Eq.(3) 
$$y''=y'*z+y*z' \tag{4}$$
and substitution from Eq.(3) to Eq.(4) and we have:
$$y''=y*z^2+y*z' \tag{5}$$
and substitution from Eq.(5) to Eq.(1) and we have
 **Riccati equation** first order and with quadratic nonlinearity:
$$z'(x)+z(x)^2+A (x)=0  \tag{6}$$
**DSolve** can't find solution!!! of this Riccati equation.

Answer (score 1):

As [David-G.-Stork](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9735/david-g-stork) mentioned, the first argument of `DSolve` needs to be a flat list.

Try to give equations and initial conditions in one list like this:

```
eqs = {(λ  x y[x])/Sqrt[1 - x] + y'[x] == 0, y[1] == 0, y'[1] == 1}
DSolve[eqs, y[x], x]
```

Still not sure if Mathematica can solf this, but now it's at least syntactically correct.

Comment: The first argument does not need to be a flat list.  Consider `DSolve[{y''[x] == y[x], {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}}, y, x]`....

Comment: This is a first order equation and you provide 2 conditions so it only has solutions for specific values of lambda?